# Nginx proxy_pass частино не работает

Tags: nginx

У меня есть такой конфиг. На N порту развернуты приложения.

```
server {
   listen 80;

   location {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:501;
    }
   location /autotest {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:502;
    }
   location /dev {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:503;
    }
   location /dev/autotest{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:504;
    }
   location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:505;
    }   
   location /dev/admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:506;
    }
}
```

Первые 4 работают корректно и доступны по имени http://servername/location/method
А последние 2 нет. К ним я могу обращаться только http://servername:port/method
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что конкретно означает «нет»? Какие ошибки, что в логах написано?

Comment: напишите что вы хотите достигнуть своим конфигом

Comment: На машине запущены API приложения, которые слушают N порт (501-506). Я могу к ним обратиться через http://servername:port/method . У каждого приложения есть N методов. т.е. method1, method2, method3 и тд.
Я хочу чтобы можно было обращаться по имени, без указания порта. т.е. 
http://servername/appname/method
В идеале для приложений из ветки dev http://dev.servername/appname/method

Comment: Не знаю что именно я сделал, но при том же конфиге теперь работает только
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:501;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:501/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /autotest/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:502/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "autotest.servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /dev/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:503/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "dev.servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /dev/autotest/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:504/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "dev.autotest.servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:505/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "admin.dev.servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /dev/admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:506/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host "dev.admin.servername";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Сделал так, заработало.